# HttpListenerException in Worker role when Start listening

Tags: azure, httplistener

I am migrating my C# console app to Azure. My app use the `HttpListener` to listen for http request on a specific port. When I try the following test code locally in a Worker role, I got an exception (similar print out in the ComputeEmulator screen) saying:

> **HttpListenerException - "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".**

Note: I have configured the port to 2020 in the service config file. I also noticed that the port retrieved from RoleEnvironment show 2020, but is that suppose to show a different port since it's supposed to be remapped to a different port than the configured external port number?

```
// ========== Test code starts ==============

string ipAddress = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Ecard"].IPEndpoint.Address.ToString();
int port = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Ecard"].IPEndpoint.Port;

string uri = @"http://" + ipAddress + ":" + port + "/";

try
{

    httpListener = new HttpListener();
    httpListener.Prefixes.Add(uri);
    httpListener.Start();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

// Test code ends.
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know much about Azure, I know a little bit about http.sys/HttpListener, so here's my attempt to help: httpListener.Prefixes.Add(ur) fails unless the process runs in admin/elevated user context. Another way to make Prefixes.Add() not fail is to have the url in question ACLed beforehand, using either netsh.exe utility, or programmatically with HttpAPI, both of which would also run in admin/elevated user context. Unless Azure operating environment does ACL (grants access rights to) the url for the user context in which your code runs, you may need to look for options other than using HttpListener.